# Set value of button as HTML content

Tags: jquery

How to change the value of a button so that it will be interpreted as HTML code? I have this:

```
<input type="button" value="Click">
```

When pressing it I do this:

```
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
$(this).prop('value', '<i class="fa fa-spinner"></i>');
```

However the content won't be a rotating spinner. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put any HTML inside an `<input type="button">` element. You'd need to use `<button>` to achieve this, along with `html()` instead of `prop()`:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $(this).prop('disabled', true).html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Click</button>
```

Note the addition of the `fa-spin` class to make the icon rotate.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set HTML into an input field. You will have to fake the situation to look like the input is rendering the spinner:

```
$("input").click(function(e){
  $(this).prop('disabled', true).css("display", "none");
  $wrapper = $("<div >");
  $(this).wrap($wrapper);
  $(this).after('<i class="fa fa-spinner"></i>');
})
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uswcfjef/